# Algebraic data type list into an actual list

Tags: list, haskell, algebraic-data-types

I am tying to create a function where I enter an Algebraic data type list, and it should output an actual list.

For example, we have a `` list1 = P `Cons` (G `Cons` Empty) ``

The Output should be: `[G,P]`

I created the following Algebraic data types:

```
data Elements = G | S | P deriving (Eq, Show)
data List a = Empty | Cons Elements (List Elements)
```

and my current function is:

```
list:: Elements -> [List]
list Empty = []
list Cons a (List b) = [a] ++ list (List b)
```

I am having trouble solving this, and would appreciate if I get some help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `[G,P]` are you absolutely 100% sure it should not be `[P, G]`?

Comment: Yes, ``P `Cons` (G `Cons` Empty)`` is `[P,G]`

But I also want to reverse it. So it should be ``[G,P]``

Comment: In your definition of List, the "a" type argument is not used.

Comment: I want to use the "Elements" data Type for "a", is that possible?
so that "a" can only be type "Elements"

Comment: Normally a final 's' letter marks plurality (in English Spanish French at least) so using "Elements" for a single basic entity is confusing. I would suggest: `data Element = G | S | P` *and then*  `data List a = Empty | Cons a (List a)`  *and then*  `data Elements = List Element` or something similar.

Comment: So make a list, then `reverse` it. If your algebraic list should be interpreted in reverse by itself, then the usual name for the data constructor is `Snoc` rather than `Cons`.

Comment: I just solved it. ``data Chain a = Empty | Join Link (Chain a) ``

Comment: It might help to consciously acknowledge that your `List` type is *exactly* the same as the built-in list type; all you've done is rename the constructors. `[]` becomes the type constructor `List` and the data constructor `[]`, while `(:)` becomes `Cons`. Nothing about how you *use* the ADT changes except for the change in names (and, well, the loss of syntactic sugar like `[P, G]` in place of `P:G:[]`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with your data types:

```
data Elements = G | S | P deriving (Eq, Show)
data List a = Empty | Cons Elements (List Elements)
```

From a technical standpoint, there's nothing wrong with `Elements`, but it's a very poor choice of name.  As others have noted, it's more usual to name the type `Element`.  The reason is that the English translation of your data type declaration is:

> "Elements" is either gold or silver or platinum.

when it would make more sense to say:

> An **"Element"** is either gold or silver or platinum

Also, when you start writing code with this type, it starts to get confusing.  If you define a value of type `Elements`:

```
e :: Elements
e = P
```

this represents a single element "platinum", and not a collection elements.  This confusion might lead you to write a `list` function with the wrong type signature because you *think* you're saying `list` takes a bunch of `Elements` but the type signature *actually* says that `list` takes only one element.

For this reason, I'm going to do a search and replace of all your code, and the rest of my answer will talk about this version using "`Element`" instead:

```
data Element = G | S | P deriving (Eq, Show)
data List a = Empty | Cons Element (List Element)

list:: Element -> [List]
list Empty = []
list Cons a (List b) = [a] ++ list (List b)

list1 = P `Cons` (G `Cons` Empty)
```

Moving on, there *is* a problem with your `List` type:

```
data List a = Empty | Cons Element (List Element)
```

You've defined a parameterized type `List a`, but then you haven't used the parameter `a` in its definition.  In other cases where you've seen a `List a` defined it was because the `a` parameter was supposed to represent the type of list items, so the same list could be used to hold `Element`s or `Int`s or whatever.  Since you want a special list data type that only holds `Element`s, you should write `List` without a parameter (on both the left-hand side and the right-hand side of this declaration):

```
data List = Empty | Cons Element List
        ^^- no "a"                  ^^- no "Element" argument
```

Now, consider the type signature for `list`:

```
list :: Element -> [List]
```

What `list` is *supposed* to do is take a list of elements like:

```
list1 = P `Cons` (G `Cons` Empty)
```

and produce a Haskell list as a result:

```
result1 = [G,P]
```

but this type signature says that `list` is going to take a single `Element` and produce a Haskell list whose items are of type `List` (i.e., a custom `List` of `Element`s), in other words, it'll produce a list of `List`s of elements.  This certainly isn't right.

In fact, `list` should take a `List` of `Element`s and return a (Haskell) list of `Element`s, so the type signature should read:

```
list :: List -> [Element]
```

Note that if you loaded up just the type declarations into GHCi and checked the types of your example argument and result:

```
ghci> data Element = G | S | P deriving (Eq, Show)
ghci> data List = Empty | Cons Element List
ghci> :type  P `Cons` (G `Cons` Empty)
P `Cons` (G `Cons` Empty) :: List     -- input is of type `List`
ghci> :type  [G,P]
[G,P] :: [Element]                    -- output is of type `[Element]`
```

this would confirm that you want a function `List -> [Element]`.

Now, your definition has two more errors:

```
list Cons a (List b) = [a] ++ list (List b)
```

Patterns like `Cons a (List b)` need to be surrounded by parentheses to match a single argument, so this should read:

```
list (Cons a (List b)) = [a] ++ list (List b)
```

There's still another problem here.  The use of `List` doesn't make sense here. `List` is a type, and it belongs in type signatures, not in patterns or expressions, at least not like this.  Haskell already knows that the second field of `Cons` is a `List`, so you don't need to tell it that.  You just need to assign that field to a variable.  If you eliminate the `List` from both sides:

```
list (Cons a b) = [a] ++ list b
```

the final definition should type check:

```
list :: List -> [Element]
list Empty = []
list (Cons a b) = [a] ++ list b
```

If you want the result in reverse order, just flip the concatenation around:

```
list :: List -> [Element]
list Empty = []
list (Cons a b) = list b ++ [a]
```

The final code:

```
data Element = G | S | P deriving (Eq, Show)
data List = Empty | Cons Element List deriving (Show)

list:: List -> [Element]
list Empty = []
list (Cons a b) = list b ++ [a]

list1 = P `Cons` (G `Cons` Empty)

main = print $ list list1  -- output [G,P]
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

I Appreciate the very detailed explanation :)